# Why is this MergeSort not working?

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I used the top-down psuedo-code from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) when creating this test code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] nums = new int[] { 17, 5, 3, 7, 6, 3, 11, 2 };
    mergeSort(nums);
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(nums[i] + " ,");
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] A) {
    int[] B = new int[A.length];
    System.arraycopy(A, 0, B, 0, A.length);
    splitMerge(B, 0, A.length, A); // sort data from B[] into A[]
}

public static void splitMerge(int[] B, int begin, int end, int[] A) {
    if (end - begin < 2)
        return;
    int middle = (end + begin) / 2;
    splitMerge(B, begin, middle, A);
    splitMerge(B, middle, end, A);
    System.out.println("begin: " + begin +  " mid: " + ((end - begin)/2) + " end: " + end + " SIZE: " + (end-begin));
    merge(B, begin, middle, end, A);

}

public static void merge(int[] B, int begin, int middle, int end, int[] A) {
    int i = begin;
    int j = middle;
    for (int k = begin; k < end; k++) {
        if (i < middle && (j >= end || B[i] <= B[j])) {
            A[k] = B[i];
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            A[k] = B[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be more or less exactly the same as the psuedo-code, so why is it not working?
Here is the output:

```
begin: 0 mid: 1 end: 2 SIZE: 2
begin: 2 mid: 1 end: 4 SIZE: 2
begin: 0 mid: 2 end: 4 SIZE: 4
begin: 4 mid: 1 end: 6 SIZE: 2
begin: 6 mid: 1 end: 8 SIZE: 2
begin: 4 mid: 2 end: 8 SIZE: 4
begin: 0 mid: 4 end: 8 SIZE: 8
6 ,3 ,11 ,2 ,17 ,5 ,3 ,7 ,
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Getting us to debug for you is too broad of a request. Do some debugging, and post back when you have a specific problem that we can help you with.

Comment: The problem should be in the "merge" method, because as the output shows, the recursion is splitting up the array into two halves correctly.

Comment: The problem is that this code *should* work, since it is from Wikipedia. If this code does not work, then Wikipedia might be showing wrong information.

Comment: It seems, `A` and `B` have been switched, when compared to the Wiki page, on the lines `splitMerge(B, begin, middle, A);` and `splitMerge(B, middle, end, A);`. I would recommend avoiding such mix-ups by copy-pasting the original meta code and then editing in-place to adjust for the specific language (temporarily, the original may be left in comments for readability). Otherwise, some inacurateness due to manual copying might creep in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `B` array contains a copy of the original array and you never change it, while you change your original `A` array.

This means that the `merge` method cannot work, since it merges two unsorted arrays (two sub-arrays of `B`, which remains unsorted throughout the algorithm).

In order to do the `merge` properly, you should copy the elements having indices from `begin` to `end` from the `A` array to the `B` array at the start of the merge method.

All you have to do is add the statement

```
System.arraycopy(A, begin, B, begin, end - begin);
```

as the first statement of your `merge` method.

i.e.:

```
public static void merge(int[] B, int begin, int middle, int end, int[] A) {
    System.arraycopy(A, begin, B, begin, end - begin);
    int i = begin;
    int j = middle;
    for (int k = begin; k < end; k++) {
        if (i < middle && (j >= end || B[i] <= B[j])) {
            A[k] = B[i];
            i = i + 1;
        } else {
            A[k] = B[j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the output

```
2 ,3 ,3 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,11 ,17 ,
```

for the given input.